# my database is not getting connected simple on jsp page build on netbeans

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, netbeans

The following is a simple code to show wheather database is connected or
 not.I am using mysql workbench and netbeans.It is showing not connected
 and the glassfish server is showing some warnings which are shown after 
 the code.

```
 code

 <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%
    Connection conn = null;

    try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conn =DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userpass?zeroDateTimeBehavior                                                          
             =convertToNull","root", "root");
         if(conn!=null)
         {
             out.print("connected to database successfully");
         }

      }catch(Exception e)
      {
       out.print("not connected to database");
    }

    %>
   </body>
   </html>

   <warning and info*/
   Info:   Loading application __admingui done in 7,651  ms
   Warning:   Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from      
         bundle:/
  Info:   Redirecting to /index.jsf
  Info:   Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...
 Warning:   Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at        
 root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
 Warning:   Cannot create update center Image for C:\Program   
 Files\glassfish->4.1.1; Update Center functionality will not be available       
 in Admin Console
```

Comment: I just want to say that Java script in JSP is bad code. Use a Servlet to pass the result to the JSP and print it via EL (Expression Langage).

For your problem, you should add the tag for glassfish.

Comment: @AxelH one thing to mention, the code between <% and %> is not a Java script code, it's java code, named scriplets. And yes, it's a bad practice to write scriplets in our days when you have EL Libraries. JavaScript != Java.

Comment: I didn't write javascript but java script since this is call a scriptlet when you write Java into the jsp between jsp tags, I call that Java script :P A bit confusing I admit, but I can recognize Java when I see it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this maybe it is a syntax error also check if you have correct jar file or not-

```
Connection conn = null;

try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 conn =DriverManager.getConnection
 ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userpass","root", "root"); //removed after userpass
     if(conn!=null)
     out.println("connected to database successfully");
     else
     out.println("not connected to database");

  }catch(Exception e)
  {
   out.println(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I will say writing database code in jsp is not good way to code.All the database code and business logic must be written in servlet or plain java class.Jsp is view, after processing from servlet , to show output we can use jsp.

```
This is just a warning, you can ignore it if you want.
```

The warning is raised because you probably have a leading slash (i.e. /) in your context-root in glassfish-web.xml (should be in the WEB-INF folder of the WAR).

You may get rid of the warning if you remove the leading slash so your glassfish-web.xml looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish     Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
<context-root>SalutationApp-war</context-root>
 </glassfish-web-app>



I hope I helped u.
```

Comment: where can i find glassfish-web.xml .Under my project name there is web-pages there is web-inf folder but no glassfish-web.xml